# Fulltext-search in php without database

Tags: php, full-text-search, search-engine

I have a really small webpage written in php (approx. 5 pages + blog entries). All pages are located in php files on the server side (no database is used). So far I managed to search inside my 'blog entries' - because these are just plain textfiles with HTML markup (I strip the tags & performing a search operation):

```
$file_name=array();
$search_string="";
if(isSet($_GET["query"])){
    $search_string=$_GET["query"];
}
$search_result="";
$files="";
$phpfilename="";
$i=0;   
if (!$search_string){
    echo 'No query entered<br />';
}else{
    if ($handle = opendir('content/')) { 
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
            if(strrchr($file, '.') === ".txt"){
                $filename[]= $file;
            }
        } 
        closedir($handle); 
    }
    foreach($filename as $value){
        $files="content/$value";
        $fp = strip_tags(file_get_contents($files));
        if(stripos($fp, $search_string)) {
            $search_result.=preg_replace('/<[^>]*>[^<]*<[^>]*>/', '', substr($fp,0,255)); // append a preview to search results
        }
        if($search_result!=""){
            echo $search_result;
        }else{
            echo "No Results<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Of course that works just because the files are plain text. But I've got also pages that are real 'php' files and want to perform a search operation on them too. But I don't want to search inside the 'php code' of course. I figured out, that I would need the preparsed files that the browser gets from the webserver - I thought about using `file_get_contents()`‎ with http requests to all my pages (ok, 'just' about 5 pages but still)...

I've read here on SO that it's considered bad practice to do so and it feels like I'm taking the wrong approach.

Any ideas & suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Edit: A example for a regular page that I want to be able to search in

**index.php**

```
<?php ob_start(); require_once("./include/common.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title><?php echo $lang['WEBSITE_TITLE']; ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword, keyword, keyword" />
<link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<!-- Header Area -->
<?php include("./include/header.php"); ?>
<?php include("./include/banner.php"); ?>
<div id="content">

<?php

    $page = '';
    if(isSet($_GET["page"])){
        $page=$_GET["page"];
    }
    switch($page){
        case 'category_1':
            include("./include/category_1.php");
            break;
        case 'about':
            include("./include/category_2.php");
            break;
        case 'contact':
            include("./include/contact.php");
            break;
        default:
            include("./include/home.php");  
    }
?>
<!-- /content --></div> 

<!-- /page --></div>
<br />
<br /><br /><br />

<!-- Footer Area -->
<?php include("./include/footer.php"); ob_end_flush(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**/include/category_1.php**

```
<?php echo '<h2>'.$lang['NAVI_CAT_1'].'</h2>'; ?>

<div id="entry">
<br/>
<?php echo $lang['CAT_1_TEXT']; ?>
</div>
```

**language file**

```
<?php
$lang = array();
$lang['NAVI_CAT_1'] = 'Category 1';
$lang['CAT_1_TEXT'] = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.';

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply ignore all that is between <?php and ?> ?

Comment: If we are talking about 5 pages, then just open them all in your browser, copy the source code to txt files, and upload them to the server, and use those in the search.

Comment: @user574632 you just invented file_get_contents() on a http request... by hand! ;)

Comment: @Jivan Because that would be the entire file in my case. For the sake of i18n I'm using a language array with the text to `echo` on the corresponding pages. Also in a page there are more files involved than just one php file (included files for html & css, language text, ...).

Comment: @user574632 Well, that would be a workaround, but I would rather want to change the pages later on & to copy all the text every time something changes is a bit heavy. Then maybe file_get_contents() on a http request is preferable.

Comment: To go more in user574632's direction, you could set up a phone line by which users would call you when they want to look for an expression, and because you know the texts by heart, you tell them where the expression is located in the page.

Comment: Use a database and update it with a dumbed down crawler periodically.

Comment: @Jivan except file_get_contents is called on every request. My point was rather that this is dealing with a tiny amount of pages, so you would be better creating a searchable document on edit, rather than parsing the same few files every request

Comment: @user574632 If you want to do that, you should set up a system where it automatically generates the "searchable" (whatever it is - document, database, etc.) and automatically re-generates them whenever a file changes. Otherwise, you are setting yourself up to have to manually re-copy each file each time you change it, and if you forget, you might not realize the searches are failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not include into a buffer and then search the buffer's contents?

```
ob_start();
include ('index.php');
$contents = ob_get_clean();
//the $contents now includes whatever the php file outputs
```

I actually use this method in production code for all kinds of things, but mainly previewing site-generated emails before users send them.  The nice thing is, you can use this on all the files, not just the php files.

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty neat solution - I didn't know there exists such a thing. Thank you!

Comment: That's funny you didn't think of it, because you use buffers in your code.  Good thing for you that buffers can be nested, right?

Comment: If you are okay with public access all the contents/pages then it is fine. Or else you could spent time to come up with XML as an alternative method to control the keyword that user can search. My idea is, better to show what you allow instead of search through all pages and folders and not show what you disallow.

Answer (score 0):

this is failed by design.
consider not using plain mixed html sides. try to use xml files or wathever.

the alternative is crawling your own side. take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  You should consider fully explaining your ideas rather than trying to condense them into the smallest possible sentences.